# Doctrine2 / Add Entity property but do not wan to create a column

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

With Doctrine 2, is it possible to add a new property to an entity to persist it in the entity manager, but NOT create a new column in the database ?

Purpose of that is to add a `explain` field to an entity and catch it with an event when UnitOfWork detects an update of one entity's value. (and perhaps send the content of the `explain` field by email, or log it, ...)

But I don't want to store this value in the database.

Comment: why dont you just create a private member for it which will get passed around with the object then fire something off the setter of the field?

Comment: Because it will not be detected by the UOW::getEntityChangeSet() no?

Comment: hmm after digging around you could hook into the ['postPersist'](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#creating-the-listener-class) event.  That way you could use the private member.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I read the doc about Doctrine lifetime events and I tried to use `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks` on my entity + a callback function `doPostPersist() { die 'something'; }` with a docblock `@ORM\PostPersist`. But nothing happens ... Is there a special configuration to use these events ?

Comment: OK, when I plug in the PostUpdate event, I can see the updated fields, but not the `explain` field ...